# img.onload gives invalid argument in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, onload

I'm trying to detect when all images in an array load and then calling a function. Works fine in all browsers but IE.

```
//Detect when all images load
for (var i = 0, cnt = 0; i < urls.length; i++){
  var img = new Image();
  if(nodeNames[i] == 'IMG'){
    //the following line is the problem, according to IE
    img.onload = myFunction;
    img.src = urls[i];
  }
  else if(nodeNames[i] === 'DIV'){
    setTimeout(myFunction(),1);
  }else{
    setTimeout(myFunction(),1);
  }
}
function myFunction(){
  //...lots of code
}
else{
loaded = 0;
for(var i = 0, len = slides.length; i < len; ++i){
slides[i].css({
'display':'none'
});
}
}
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout(myFunction,1);` perhaps? Although that would not be a reason for it only not to work on IE.

Comment: Consider using jQuery's Deferred object.

Comment: That code looks bogus starting right after "myFunction()" - is that just stray stuff you accidentally posted here?

Comment: this also doesn't take into account for cached images. If the image is cached, the onload event may not trigger. You would need to check the readystate and complete properties to see if the image is already cached. For an example, see this jQuery plugin: https://github.com/tentonaxe/jQuery-preloadImages/blob/master/jquery.preloadimages.js

Comment: @pointy Yeah - that part of the code means nothing out of context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the document onload event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images and sub-frames have finished loading.

For individual image loads see jQuery's [load event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) which is different from the identically named [ajax load](http://api.jquery.com/load/). This will execute when the image loads.

```
$('img').load( function() {
    //do something
});
```

**Update**

I think this is what OP is after. This bit of code will get each img once it is completely loaded. Once it loads a new image is created based on it and inserted into a new area (say a slideshow). In this example fiddle you can see that the two largest images will usually end up at the end of the copied image list. I also used a settimeout to load a final image after three seconds and this should always up at the end.

http://jsfiddle.net/HN9KU/4/

```
$('img').load( function () {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = $(this).attr('src');    
    $('#showonload').append(img);
});
```

Comment: Well, if you want a callback when loading an image via an "Image" browser object, then jQuery won't do you much good.

Comment: @Pointy jQuery can handle that too. `$(new Image()).load(fn).attr('src','foo.jpg');`

Comment: @Pointy - hmmm, I think I missed point of OP's question. Can you please explain what he is doing?

Comment: wow I've never tried that but I guess I shouldn't be surprised :-) As to what the OP is doing, I'm not sure; probably something like delaying the reveal of a slideshow widget until all the images are cached.

Comment: Ahh, I finally think I get it. You have a slideshow, and as each image is loaded you add it into the slideshow. If you did not do that then you could have blanks in your slideshow. I added an example to my answer that can hopefully answer this.

Comment: Thanks for that! Won't quite work for my application but I'm sure someone will find it useful.